# Sqlite Transaction

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions, android-sqlite

is it save to begin and commit a transaction by retrieving the database two times with getWriteableDatabase(). I have this scenario if I want to use two DAOs in one transaction

Something like this:

```
SqliteDatabase db = userDao.getWriteableDatabase();

try{

    userDao.insert(firstname, lastname);
    addressDao.insert(street);
    // commit
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
catch(Exception e){
    // rollback
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Where:

```
class UserDao extends Dao {

    public void insert(String firstname, String lastname){

       SqliteDatabase db = getWriteableDatabase();

       ...
       db.insertOrThrow(...);
     }

}

class AdressDao extends Dao {

    public void insert(String street){

       SqliteDatabase db = getWriteableDatabase();

       ...
       db.insertOrThrow(...);
     }

}
```

`getWriteableDatabase()` is just a shortcut for `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()`

So is it safe to work in this way in a transaction or does getWriteableDatabase() returns another instance and therefore the transaction is no longer in the right scope?

If so i could pass the SqliteDatabase as parameter to the DAO, like

```
SqliteDatabase db = userDao.getWriteableDatabase();

try{

    userDao.insert(db, firstname, lastname);
    addressDao.insert(db, street);
    // commit
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
catch(Exception e){
    // rollback
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Scope is not even the problem here. You cannot open the same database file twice. In older Android versions you risk data corruption and loss. In newer versions you'd get an exception. If above code works for you, then your Dao base class seems to cache the database connection. This is what SqliteOpenHelper does internally.

Comment: I use and share the same SqliteOpenHelper in every Dao base class, so the databasefile will not be opened twice.

Answer (score 0):

getWritableDatabase() creates the instance the first time that gets called and cache the returned value. So you're not opening the db twice and yes, it's safe.